# Spring hibernate Could not load JDBC driver class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc

I don't know what to do. I add postgres to maven dependencies and it builds successful. But when I run it I got the exception

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
>   PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver]

PLZ help

EDIT

This is my pom

```
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: how do you run it? do you have the driver in your classpath?

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot, you need to create an executable JAR with all the dependencies packaged in it.

Comment: Yes I got it in classpath. I run it from Eclipse as java application. I'm not using Spring Boot

Comment: Please include your `pom.xml`, and anything else you think would be useful for us to analyze the issue. There may be something missing and I cannot tell without knowing more detail.

Comment: I edit my  question

Comment: @R1K0 Thanks. Your dependencies seem to be correct but I'm not so sure about your Spring version. Could you also include snippet of `<build>`?

Comment: Your configuration is wrong ... `com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver` should be `org.postgresql.Driver`. Also not sure what spring dependency you are using but that thing doesn't exist... There is no 3.7.3 version of Spring, there is of the Spring IDE but that is a whole different thing.

Comment: Ok. I edit my question. I use it now "org.postgresql.Driver". And I edit my pom to use sping - now it builds sccessful. But error still happens

Comment: OH. My fault. Now it works. Problem when I use "org.postgresql.Driver" I use com, not org. Thank you